# Answering an already answered question

Tags: discussion, support

I am new here (at least as an answerer, though I have been checking the "hot" questions and answers for several months now).

My question is:
Any question will have a "first" answer at some point of time. I have noticed that most of the answers have the critical (giveaway/spoiler) parts "hidden" until we hover the mouse-pointer over them. My understanding was this is to help other answerers independently "try" to answer on their own.
Now I realise that even an innocent/independent "duplicate" answer may be frowned upon.
So, if a (reasonably new) question has an answer (or more) already with the "hidden" parts, do I "uncover" them and see them first to ensure I am not repeating one of them? If yes, why even "hide" them in the first place?
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're solving the puzzle *for the fun of it* then you should ignore hidden spoilers (that's why they're hidden) and there's no need to post your answer at all.

If you're solving the puzzle *so you can win Meaningless Internet Points* then you should check the hidden spoilers so that you don't duplicate someone else's work.

If *you're solving the puzzle for fun, but would like to collect Meaningless Internet Points if you can*, you should ignore hidden spoilers, solve the puzzle, and then check the hidden spoilers and refrain from posting a solution that duplicates something already posted.

(The last of those paragraphs is probably the commonest case.)

To address your final questions a bit more explicitly: The spoiler-hiding is to let you solve the puzzle for yourself if you want to. If you do that and end up with a solution that doesn't add anything to existing ones, then you shouldn't post what you did; the fun of solving should suffice. If the fun of solving *isn't* enough and you only want to solve the puzzle if you have a chance to post a solution and collect Meaningless Internet Points for it, then you should check what answers other people have posted so you don't waste your time.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Perhaps this info should be there on the tour page? As an aside, I especially liked the mention of meaningless internet points.

Comment: I think the tour is exactly the same as it is for every other Stack Exchange site. Puzzling is different from most SE sites because of the solving-puzzles-for-fun element, which isn't really present on (say) Stack Overflow. I'm not sure what could usefully be said about spoiler markup that would be applicable to all SE sites.